# CreateFile function in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, createfile

I want to use CreateFile() function in Visual C++. when I am using it in this way:-

```
{
BOOL bTest=FALSE;
DWORD dwNumRead=0;
HANDLE hFile=CreateFile(L"D:\\a.dat",GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,
                              NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
bTest= CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

The value of bTest is coming out to be False and the file is not created.
Please, if possible, illustrate an example to create a file using CreateFile and tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"OPEN_EXISTING : Opens a file or device, only if it exists. If the specified file or device does not exist, the function fails". That's your problem, I bet.

`GetLastError()` would tell you more, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to create a file use CREATE_ALWAYS or CREATE_NEW instead of OPEN_EXISTING.

CreateFile function
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is you are getting an `Invalid File Handle` in `CreateFile` function because of  the parameter `dwCreationDisposition` where you specify `OPEN_EXISTING`. It means that `Opens a file or device, only if it exists.`  Change it to `CREATE_ALWAYS` or `CREATE_NEW` it will work.

Comment: thank you it worked with CREATE_NEW instead of OPEN_EXISTING.